# How to distinguish between left and right mouse click with jQuery on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

this code work 100% in "google Chrome Browser" but its not working on "Firefix" 
how i solve this problem?

```
    $(".one_post").click(function() {

    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
            break;
        case 2:
            $(this).target = "_blank";
            window.open($(this).attr("href"));
            break;
        }
    });

     $(".os_new_ads_lis_city").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });

     $(".os_new_ads_list_category").click(function() {
    window.document.location = $(this).attr("href");
    });
```

Comment: For Firefox specifically, use [*event.button*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent.button), but don't expect it to be reliable (or even implemented) in other browsers.

Comment: thanks but i try event.button and its not working

Comment: Trying to detect the right mouse button is problematic, as [*this reference*](http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html) points out (and [*this one*](http://perrymitchell.net/article/detecting-which-mouse-button-was-pressed/)). It's a bit old, but if you have a click listener then it's only supposed to respond to left (i.e. primary button) clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of click, use mousedown event, as right click opens context menu, you need to use mouse down instead of mouse click, else prevent event bubbling after right click,

```
$('#btn').on("mousedown",function(e){
    //  your code
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/Ts5Dp/1/) is a small fiddle demo of mouse down which will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mouseup](http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) or [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) instead:

```
$('.one_post').mouseup(function() {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('Left');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('Middle');
            break;
        case 3:
            alert('Right');
            break;
    }
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7gHXK/)